# Cannot find module 'faker' or its corresponding type declarations.(2307)

Tags: typescript, testcafe, faker.js

I was trying to use 'faker' with TypeScript in TestCafe Studio. But I'm getting an error saying **Cannot find module 'faker' or its corresponding type declarations.(2307)**

```
import * as faker from 'faker';
```

This is what I have tried in TestCafe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **faker** package has been discontinued.

To resolve this, try doing the following:

```bash
npm install @faker-js/faker --save-dev
# or yarn 
yarn add @faker-js/faker -D
```

You can override the import to:

```js
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';
```

**Documentation** [@faker-js/faker](https://fakerjs.dev/guide/#installation)

Comment: thank you for your response. Actually, I have asked the same question from DevExpress and got the same answer and it resolved my question [https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1063835/cannot-integrate-third-party-tools-with-tectcafe-studio].

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct for the use of any other person. Thank you again

Comment: import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";

Answer (score 1):

Faker package is discontinued and may not be used anymore.

Comment: Hi @omidh! I recently found out that still faker can be used as a third party too. Refer the below ticket. https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1063835/cannot-integrate-third-party-tools-with-tectcafe-studio